# jQuery - Detect click on Browser Back button and submit form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a simple form with post method. Here it is:

```
<form method="post" id="ParseSD" action="../../../../../purchase-product">
    <input type="text" id="SDLINK" name="LINK" class="LinkInput" placeholder="Поставете линк от SportsDirect.com">
    <button id="SubmitButton">Вземи продукта</button>
</form>
```

I paste a link in the input and submit the form. Everything is fine. I can go thrue different links and submit them.

However when i submit a form i want to catch the click on Back button.

I need that because when a user clicks on the Back button of the browser, the browser ask the user to resubmit the page by refreshing it. I want to make a code which will automaticly resubmit the last submited form.

Here is the code that i have so far for binding the back button click:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {

    window.history.pushState('forward', null, './#forward');

    $(window).on('popstate', function() {
      alert('Back button was pressed.');
    });

  }
});
```

However i do not know how to AUTO resubmit the last form. Is it even possible ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm pretty sure the browser will ask you that before the script runs. Also, for payment type forms, this might be a very bad idea, as the payment would be processed twice. I am pretty sure there's a standard way to handle the form submit thing, probably with browser redirects on success?

Answer (score 0):

Try the Following:

```
$( "#ParseSD" ).submit(function( event ) {
  //After Submit
});
```